# Is it possible to auto expire tasks in a pull queue?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm running into the scenario that I'm queuing up tasks in a pull queue for a worker, which after a certain point in time should expire if the worker did not get to them for any reason. The `eta` and `countDown` options seem to affect when the task becomes visible; is there an option to set a time to live on a pull queue task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The tasks in a pull queue must be deleted by a 'worker' (i.e. your application). You could have a worker that just deletes tasks depending on the age of the task.

Comment: Thanks, that was my alternative approach as well